# cannot insert in sqlite database in android

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I create this table:

```
"create table "  + DATABASE_TABLE + " ("
    + KEY_ROWID + " integer primary key autoincrement not null, "
    + KEY_TITLE + " text not null, "
    + KEY_BODY + " text not null, " + KEY_DATE_TIME + " text not null);"
```

and here is what I do for inserting:

```
ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
initialValues.put("title", title);
initialValues.put("body", body);
initialValues.put("abc", anc);
return mDb.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, initialValues);
```

but due to some error my app force closes. Help me out please...

Logcat errors:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
com.maddy.task_reminder.ReminderDbAdapter.createReminder(ReminderDbAdapter.java:133)
06-09 23:28:44.112: E/AndroidRuntime(412):  at com.maddy.task_reminder.edit_activity$4.onClick(edit_activity.java:143)
```

Comment: this is what i am getting in LogCat...

Comment: What are the values of the `KEY_` constants? Which one of them is `"abc"`?

Comment: i am sorry i ve renamed that field to abc letme again post it

Comment: ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
 initialValues.put("title", title);
 initialValues.put("body", body);
 initialValues.put("reminder_date_time", reminderDateTime);
 return mDb.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, initialValues);

Comment: Edit your question and paste your code snippet that is generating the error and your Logcat content as well.

Comment: now its perfectly fine question .....

Comment: Is by any chance `mDb` null at the point you call `insert`?

Comment: no its just an empty database nothing else....

Comment: how can this null mDb problem be removed...?

Comment: What is line 143 in ReminderDbAdapter?

Comment: mDbHelper.createReminder(title, body, reminderDateTime);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are following the generic DBAdapter examples on the web, check that you call:

```
mDbHelper.open();
```

in your Activity. Otherwise `mDb` is never instantiated in your database helper class, it is always `null`.

**Addition from Comment:**

So this is your `open()` method.

```
public ReminderDbAdapter open() throws SQLException { 
    mDbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(mCtx); 
    mDb = mDbHelper.getWritableDatabase(); 
    return this; 
}
```

If your ReminderDbAdapter constructor doesn't look like this:

```
public ReminderDbAdapter(Context context) {
    ...
    mCtx = context;
    open(); // Do you have this line?
}
```

Then you need to explicitly call `ReminderDbAdapter.open()` in your activity, possibly like this:

```
ReminderDbAdapter mDbHelper = new ReminderDbAdapter(this); 
mDbHelper.open();
```

Comment: The safest place is immediately after creating it. `DbHelper mDbHelper = new DbHelper(this); mDbHelper.open();`

Comment: dont you think contructor will open the db helper as code shows below....:
     public ReminderDbAdapter open() throws SQLException {
 
    mDbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(mCtx);
 mDb = mDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
 return this;
 }

Comment: ya as you can see constructor is opening database in writing mode

Comment: I don't see your constructor anywhere. `public ReminderDbAdapter open()` is a method of the adapter class **not** the constructor.

Comment: i cant chat cozz of reputation thing and okk letme try this thing calling open

Comment: thank you....:)) error removed...i am sort of new to android and thanx alot for helping sam.....:))

Comment: and can you please tell me the usage of context i am kind of confused about it.....

Comment: Glad you are making progress, good luck! Please mark the answer as solved by clicking the checkmark. And this should help understand Context a little better: [What is Context in Android?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3572463/1267661)

Answer (score 0):

If you look at 
        `java.lang.NullPointerException
         com.maddy.task_reminder.ReminderDbAdapter.createReminder(ReminderDbAdapter.java:133)
         06-09 23:28:44.112: E/AndroidRuntime(412):  at        com.maddy.task_reminder.edit_activity$4.onClick(edit_activity.java:143)`

You have errors at `edit_activity.java:143` and `ReminderDbAdapter.java:133`. Whats there?

And my code for the same thing looks like this

```
    `public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + DATABASE_TABLE + " (" +
                KEY_ROWID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
                KEY_NAME + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                KEY_REL + " TEXT NOT NULL);"
        );
    }`
```

and

```
public long createEntry(String name, String rel) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put(KEY_NAME, name);
    cv.put(KEY_REL, rel);
    return water.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, cv);
}
```

and it works fine.

Comment: in edit_activity......    
on line
mDbHelper.createReminder(title, body, reminderDateTime);

and in reminderdbadaptor
on line
return mDb.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, initialValues);

Comment: @webstreet The easiest way to add a block of code here in SO is to highlight the code and press `<ctrl>+k`.

Comment: The author is performing an insertion not an update, he won't need the row id.

Comment: yea sql is not case sensitive

Comment: Check out my project with sort of the same thing... https://github.com/jordanbtahabsim/Family-Tree/tree/master/src/com/webstreetlabs/FamilyTree